# Uploading an image doesn't use the new clickable image format

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

Since some time, when you insert an image through the website, the format of the image in Markdown is different from before to make its clickable.

Old:

```
![description][1]
```

New:

```
[![description][1]][1]
```

This is a nice feature, but the iOS app wasn't updated in the process (and possibly the android app too). The consistency is broken now.

Can this be included please?

---

- App Version: 1.3.2.229
- Device: iPhone7,2
- OS Version: Version 8.4.1 (Build 12H321)

Comment: Not a bug since the apps were never meant to be 100% mirror image, e.g. in the app we have "reply to comment" option which doesn't exist in the web version. But +1 for nice to have feature. :)

Comment: And here I was wondering about that duplicate brackets after uploading :-)

Comment: This is indeed an unfortunate side effect of the recent change we've made — images that link to themselves behave quite differently on the site vs. the app. We're not sure how to fix it yet, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be added in the next build.

The app uses a port of PageDown, [SEMarkdownEditor](https://github.com/bnickel/SEMarkdownEditor), to power its markdown toolbar so every once in a while I need to check in to see if there are any updates and port them.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for fixing this. I will ping back if I experience any issues.

Comment: Do you know if this is an issue with the Android app too?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I would assume yes. I think Kasra ported from my code.

Comment: Ah okay. No need to report this then.